# Sum of three bounded triangular numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics

Every nonnegative integer can be written (eventually in many ways) as a sum of three triangular numbers by the [Gauss Eureka theorem](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/rsinai/Site/Publications_files/On%20the%20representation%20of%20integers.pdf).

> What is the smallest positive integer $n=n_m$ which can **not** be written in the form $$n=\binom{a}{2}+\binom{b}{2}+\binom{c}{2}.$$ subject to $\max(a,b,c) \le m?$

The answers for $m$ from $1$ to 60 are

$  \begin {array}{cccccccccc} 1&4&8&11&24&29&29&47&68&68
\\95&99&137&141&173&173&245&281&314&314
\\314&407&419&419&470&470&617&617&711&800
\\863&911&911&911&911&1118&1118&1118&1118&1118
\\1383&1433&1433&1679&1679&1679&1868&1868&1868&1868
\\1868&2360&2493&2493&2519&2925&3044&3044&3098&3098
\end {array}
$

The sequence does not seem to be in the OEIS even with a superseeker search. It just seems a curious sequence. Any information would be welcome. What bounds or asymptotics can be established? It would appear that $n_m \lt m^2$ although $m_{105}=11018 \lt 11025=105^2$ leaves some doubt. I'd conjecture (rashly) that $$\limsup \frac{n_m}{m^2}=1$$ but $n_{110}=n_{111}=n_{112}=n_{113}=11625$ and $\frac{11625}{113^3} \approx 0.91$ so the $\liminf$ might be less. I wonder what explains the repeated values and what can be said about them.

**UPDATE** Noam makes a nice argument that $\lim \frac{n_m}{m^2}=3/2.$ I'd accept it if it was an answer and not a comment. Let me spell out that $8\binom{t}{2}+1=(2t+1)^2$ so $n=\binom{a}{2}+\binom{b}{2}+\binom{c}{2}$ exactly if $8n+3=(2a+1)^2+(2b+1)^2+(2c+1)^2$ and this allows one to pull in results on sums of squares.

I still don't see why things such as $n_{36}=n_{37}=n_{38}=n_{39}=n_{40}$ happen,  but I have not thought about it very deeply.

For any fixed $k$, $n_m \lt \frac{3m^2}{2}-km$ with finitely many exceptions. so one could wonder about things like $\frac{3m^2}{2}-\sqrt{m^3}.$ However this result was great for [the problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/107944) I wanted to apply it to. I would have mentioned the connection sooner but the answer came before I ggot to that.

Comment: I get 1,1,4,7 to start.  Perhaps you can tell us what you did to compute the values?  Gerhard "And They Aren't Triangular Numbers" Paseman, 2012.09.25

Comment: They do count triangles in complete graphs,but triangular numbers have a 2 in the bottom of the choice notation.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.09.25

Comment: I checked a couple of cases to verify that you meant $a \choose 2$ instead of $a \choose 3$, then made that edit. The question with $a \choose 3$ is not absurd, though, if $a$ could be negative.

Comment: Given the other discussion about counting triangles ain graphs, I would not have arrived at that conclusion.  Doesn't mean you're wrong, Douglas.  Gerhard "Maybe I'm Not Wrong Instead" Paseman, 2012.09.25

Comment: The question has an obvious analog for the "four-square theorems".
Has this analog been considered?



Comment: The limit of $n_m / m^2$ is $3/2$.  Writing $n$ as a sum of three
triangular numbers is equivalent to writing $8n+3$ as a sum of
three (necessarily odd) squares.  It is known that the 
integer solutions of $x^2+y^2+z^2=8n+3$ are asymptotically
equidistributed on the sphere of radius $(8n+3)^{1/2}$
[though this uses Siegel's ineffective lower bound on the
number of solutions].  In particular, for each $\epsilon>0$
there's a solution with $\max(x,y,z) < (1+\epsilon) \min(x,y,z)$
once $n > n_0(\epsilon)$, etc.


Comment: Is the sequence $n_m$ in Sloane's OEIS yet?

Comment: I don't think it is. I even did a superseeker search and that turned up nothing. I'll check the 8n+3 transformation.

Comment: One ought to submit it!

Answer (score 6):

I get $n_{m} > m^2$ for the following values of $m$ (up to 322):
$$\eqalign{ &118, 139, 140, 141, 152, 153, 176, 177, 179, 180, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 188,\cr     &189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 209, 
210,\cr     &220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 
236,\cr     &242, 243, 244, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 
265,\cr     &266, 267, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 278, 279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 
285,\cr     &286, 287, 288, 289, 290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 300, 
301,\cr    &302, 303 }$$

Comment: Ha, and I somewhat arbitrarily stopped at $115$.

Comment: Are there any examples of $n_m > \frac32 m^2$?